# How to display data in window explorer using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser, bootstrap-modal

I am displaying data into bootstrap modal window but my requirement is to display this data in window explorer , So on `serverFiles()` i want to open window explorer and display data into it and have some window explorer feature like sorting etc. is it possible using angularjs to use $scope variable values in window explorer ? After search on google i could not find feasable solution Any idea how to acheive this task ?

parent.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info  btn-md" ng-click="serverFiles()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span></button>
```

modal.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>
            <p ng-click="sortType = 'fileDate'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                Date
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'fileDate' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'fileDate' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
            </p>
        </th>
        <th>Download</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in data | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
        <td>{{file.filename}}<label ng-show="$last">currently recording</label></td>
        <td>{{file.fileDate |date : "dd.MM.y"}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="downloadServerFile(file.filename)">download</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.serverFiles = function() {
    $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/view/modals/serverModal.html',
        controller: 'ServerFilesCtrl'
    })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "browser window"?

Comment: i should say window explorer

Comment: That's totally impossible.  You cannot interact with the rest of the user's computer.

Comment: You are, of course, free to write a sortable grid in HTML / JS.

Comment: any reference or example ?

Comment: Search Google for Javascript sortable grid.